# Spring WebService Multiple @PayloadRoot

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-ws

I'm setting up an @Endpoint to handle the following Soap message:

```
<Envelope xmlns:A="namespaceA" xmlns:B="namespaceB">
  <SOAP:Header/>
  <Body>
    <A:PayloadOne/>
    <B:PayloadTwo/>
  </Body>
</Envelope>
```

My method inside the @Endpoint class looks like the following. This works successfully but then I don't have the ability to access the PayloadTwo object.

```
@PayloadRoot(localPart = "PayloadOne", uri = "namespaceA")
void receive(@RequestPayload PayloadOne value) {...}
```

I'd like to setup my method so I can receive as method parameters, both payloads. For example:

```
@PayloadRoots({ 
  @PayloadRoot(localPart = "PayloadOne", uri = "namespaceA"), 
  @PayloadRoot(localPart = "PayloadTwo", uri = "namespaceB") 
})
void receive(@RequestPayload PayloadOne value1, @RequestPayload PayloadTwo value2) {...}
```

Is that possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have not worked with Spring Boot `@Endpoint` in a while, but unless anything has changed recently, what you want is not possible. However, as a workaround, you can modify your SOAP message to add a wrapper:

```
<Envelope xmlns:A="namespaceA" xmlns:B="namespaceB">
  <SOAP:Header/>
  <Body>
    <A:PayloadWrapper>
      <A:PayloadOne/>
      <B:PayloadTwo/>
    </A:PayloadWrapper>
  </Body>
</Envelope>
```

Create a class that wraps `PayloadOne` and `PayloadTwo`:

```java
public class PayloadWrapper {
  private PayloadOne payloadOne;
  private PayloadTwo payloadTwo;

  // Public getters/setters.
}
```

Then change your method:

```java
@PayloadRoot(localPart = "PayloadWrapper", uri = "namespaceA")
public void receive(@RequestPayload PayloadWrapper payloadWrapper) {
  PayloadOne payloadOne = payloadWrapper.getPayloadOne();
  PayloadTwo payloadTwo = payloadWrapper.getPayloadTwo();
  ...
}
```

Comment: This could work however I do not have control over the incoming message as it is from a third party. I did manage to come up with a workaround using a MethodArgumentResolver. Since I failed to mention that I didn't have control over the incoming content, your answer would suffice as an answer so I will award the points to you. Thank you for taking the time to answer my question.

Answer (score 0):

For those looking for the approach I used leveraging the MethodArgumentResolver, I did the following.

The @Endpoint class method:

```
@PayloadRoot(localPart = "PayloadOne", namespace = "A")
void receive(@RequestPayload @Valid PayloadOne payloadOne,
             @PayloadTwoRequestPayload @Valid PayloadTwo payloadTwo)
```

My class to support the custom @PayloadTwoRequestPayload annotation:

```
@RequiredArgsConstructor
@Slf4j
public class PayloadTwoPayloadMethodProcessor implements MethodArgumentResolver {

  private final Jaxb2Marshaller marshaller;

  @Override
  public boolean supportsParameter(MethodParameter methodParameter) {
    return methodParameter.hasParameterAnnotation(PayloadTwoRequestPayload.class);
  }

  @Override
  public Object resolveArgument(MessageContext messageContext, MethodParameter methodParameter)
      throws Exception {
    val byteArrayOutputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

    messageContext.getRequest().writeTo(byteArrayOutputStream);
    
    SoapMessage soapMessage = new SaajSoapMessageFactory(MessageFactory.newInstance())
        .createWebServiceMessage(new ByteArrayInputStream(byteArrayOutputStream.toByteArray()));
    Document soapDocument = soapMessage.getDocument();
    Element payloadTwoElement = getElementByTagNameNs(soapDocument,
        "namespaceB", "PayloadTwo");
    return marshaller.unmarshal(new DOMSource(payloadTwoElement));
  }
}
```

The MethodArgumentResolver must be registered with Spring's Web Service configuration:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWs
@RequiredArgsConstructor
@Slf4j
public class WebServiceConfiguration extends WsConfigurerAdapter {

  private final Jaxb2Marshaller marshaller;

  @Override
  public void addArgumentResolvers(List<MethodArgumentResolver> argumentResolvers) {
    argumentResolvers.add(new PayloadTwoPayloadMethodProcessor(marshaller));
    super.addArgumentResolvers(argumentResolvers);
  }
}
```